# Размещение заголовка в приложении

Tags: android

Хочу чтобы заголовок приложения располагался по центру тулбара. Создала textView, настроила гравити.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Теперь два заголовка - слева и по центру. Удалить первый не получается. Как правильнее это сделать? Может не стоило создавать textView и есть другой способ. Подскажите

Comment: приложите скриншот

Comment: @АнтонМартынов готово

Comment: может ты заголовок еще в тулбар сетишь?

Comment: В том и вопрос. Как оставить только добавленный в тулбар. Или же если добавленный удалю, то как расположить по центру первый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение вашей проблемы:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: помогло. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.sad);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}
```